# Makefile weird percent text-pattern behaviour

Tags: c++, makefile

Good day,

Consider the following portion of a Makefile:

```
OBJECTS := $(patsubst %.cpp,%,$(wildcard Tests/*.cpp)) 
TEST_EXECUTABLE := $(patsubst Tests/%, Tests/run-%,$(OBJECTS))  
TESTF_EXECUTABLE := $(patsubst Tests/%, Tests/runF-%,$(OBJECTS))  

all: $(OBJECTS)

test: $(TEST_EXECUTABLE)    
test_formatted: $(TESTF_EXECUTABLE)     

runF-%:%
    ./$^ --output_format=XML --log_level=test_suite > $(^)-report.xml   

run-%:%
    ./$^
```

**Summary**: 
Now focus on **TEST_EXECUTABLE**, it contains the list of target object files for corresponding c++ files in Test/ folder. It produces a lot of executables so I want to call all the executables in **make test** or **make test_formatted**. To do so, both **test** and **test_formatted** call **run** and **runF** and executing the executables.

**Problem**:
My understanding of **runF-%** is when I have **run-Tests/executable**, it should match the pattern of **runF-** and the **%** is then replace with the **Tests/executable** thus **./Tests/Executable** should work. But that is not the case. When I do that I get

```
make: *** No rule to make target `run-Tests/executable', needed by `test'.  Stop.
```

I thought the pattern should be recognized, but apparently not. Instead I accidentally mess around just to get the tests running and that's how arrive to the Makefile showed above. In other words, I have to but **run-** before the executable, which doesnt makes sense at all. In that case it shouldn't work, since **run-%** would just have **%** as **executable**, not being to locate the executable file. THIS DOESNT MAKES SENSE. Although my file is in a working condition, I'd love it if someone clear up the some concept misunderstandings. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your understanding is back to front.  Check the [docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html); the *second* argument to `patsubst` is the replacement.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I know, and its working appropriately. My problem is **run-%**, ignore patsubst. I even echoed it and it intended output.

Comment: I cannot reproduce (nor understand) your error. The `test` rule should require `Tests/run-executable`, not `run-Tests/executable`.